# python - assistance with "nested" lists

Tags: python

My list looks something like this

`[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]`, except bigger

How can I print the first value of each pair? For example, in that example, I'd just like to print 'a' and 'c'.

I should also add, the list is randomly generated so I won't know the contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

for a, _ in my_list:
    print a
```

The fact that we can do `for a, _ in my_list` is because of Python's tuple unpacking. The `_` is the pythonic way of saying we don't care about that variable and we are not going to use it (as opposed to calling it `b` or something else).

Comment: The list could by anything. As long as it is a list of 2-element tuples, the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
first_items = [a for (a, b) in l]
print first_items
```

Answer (score 1):

The print statement does not have to depend upon how many elements are in the tuple:

```
my_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

for item in my_list:
    print item[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print list(map(operator.itemgetter(0),my_list))
```